MongoDB batch document update strategy with Spring Batch
I am trying to update multiple ‘MongoDB’ documents of a collection in TEST database with the same collection in LIVE database using Spring Batch’.
For this purpose I thought to delete the corresponding documents in the target collection and then insert documents from source collection as it is faster than to update each document one by one in a batch. But as the process repeats for each batch, I need a more robust solution.
So, is there a strategy to update batch documents in ‘MongoDB’ ?
And regarding to ‘Spring Batch’ side, is it possible to remove corresponding documents via a tasklet and then process to write? But ad the read operation repeats for each batch, I think it would only be possible in a separate step rather than in the same one?
